# Facebook Graph retrieve post informations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm totally new with Facebook Graph. I don't know if it's possible, I think it's not after some researches, but it seems so weird to be unable to do that kind of thing that I prefer ask.

I have create an app. And I have successfully bind this app to an Android app.

From this app, I want to load some public posts from public pages where I already know post ID and page ID.

When I try, I get "(#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token"...

Do you confirm it is impossible to load a public post from a public page without certify my facebook app ? (I don't own that page)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is impossible to get data of public pages without approval for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS).

Comment: We are applying for the Page Public Content Access permission, and have read the documentation. We are looking for help with some of the answers to the questions.  Is it appropriate to post one of our answers here to get advice, or are there other resources available?

Comment: you should either create a new thread on stackoverflow, or ask in the official facebook developers group on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/